# Error to upload images to the server with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm tryng to upload images through a form with this code

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, './uploads/users/')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, "user" + Date.now() + file.originalname);
}
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.post('/upload-avatar', [md_auth.authenticated, upload.single('file0')], UserController.uploadAvatar);
```

The problem is wen i try to send it, console throws an error 'md_auth' is not declared or undefined, do you know how t fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

the variable `md_auth` on the last line is never defined, causing your error. You must initialize that variable at somepoint in order to use it.

Comment: Thanks i'm going to analyze the code because i'm learning to use multer library and that code teacher gave me i don't understand